# Is IdentityService available in ASP.NET Core 2 Release?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have ASP.NET Core created using MVC template with individual authentication.

In ASP.NET Core 1.1 ApplicationDbContext was used for identity.

Then in Core 2 Preview they added IdentityService instead, so I modified my project to use it.

[image]

But now after Core 2 Release I see they returned back to use ApplicationDbContext, how it was in Core 1.1.

So when I open project I get a lot of errors:

[image]

Should I install some Nuget? But I see only version 1.0 Preview for IdentityService:

[image]

Maybe I should return back and use ApplicationDbContext for identity instead?

**UPDATE**: Just found on GitHub: [ASP.NET Core Identity as a service](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1187)